# Can I specify the schema of a Dataframe that I return from a function?

Tags: rust, rust-polars

Something like

```rust
fn parse_and_create_df() -> Dataframe {
    // function returns DF that adheres to a schema I defined.
}
```

I want to ensure that my API returns a consistent type of Dataframe.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Before you return, get [`schema()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.schema) and `assert!()` its properties.